# VS Code: Relative imports (linting)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

I have a multi-directory project. I use absolute imports for each directory. For example,

```
main_dir
|
| - sub_dir1
      |
      | - a.py (has say class A)
| - sub_dir2
      |
      | - b.py (imports class A. Syntax:  from subdir1.a import A)
```

When I run it in the terminal, from main_dir, it works fine.
However, this import gives me an "unresolved import 'differential_diagnosis.src.algorithm'Python(unresolved-import)" in VS code. I do not know how to fix this.

The biggest challenge I face because of this is that I cannot use the peek feature to look at what the member functions of class A do.

I have raised a similar ticket on GitHub [Project](https://github.com/tht13/Python-vscode/issues/49).

Comment: Two things. One, what folder do you have open in VS Code? Is it `main_dir` or do you have the folder that contains `main_dir` open as your workspace? Two, the correct repo for the Python extension is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add these codes in your python file:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The interpreter only can search these paths to find modules. Python will only automatically add the folder which contains the current python file to `sys.path`.

'The path of 'sub_dir1' should not be found in `sys.path`. You need to add these settings in launch.json file:

```
"env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
```

Then your workspace path will be added to `sys.path`.

If *main_dir* is the workspace folder, then you can change `from subdir1.a import A` to `from main_dir.subdir1.a import A`.

If not, it should be changed to `from {workspaceName}.{folder}....main_dir.subdir1 import A`, and you should add a `__init__.py` file in every folder to change the folder to a python package.

Answer (score 0):

You should place some code of what you are trying to do. What I can say is that Python looks for modules in the import search path. First it looks for built-in modules, Python looks in the sys.path variable which is initialized by the directory of the original script + PATH shell variable + some installation dependent default.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

To guarantee that your imports can be found, you can do:

```
sys.path.append(pathname_to_module)
```

just before you import a module.

Comment: I do not think it worked. 
import sys
sys.path.append("F:\dir1\dir2\dir3\src")
print(sys.path)
from knowledge_repository.src.age_distributions import **,***, \
    ****, ******

* has a proper name. I was not sure if I am allowed to share things publicly.
I printed the path as you can see and the path was added correctly.